# How to determining why an Erlang application is not starting?

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to start an Erlang app that is failing. All I see in the shell is:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 7-Jan-2010::17:37:42 ===
    application: ui
    exited: {shutdown,{ui_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: temporary
```

How can I get Erlang to give me more information as to why the application is not starting? There currently is no other output in the shell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try launching the shell with more logging support:

`erl -boot start_sasl`

this might get give a bit more details.

Comment: If you already have an open Erlang shell then type: application:start(sasl).

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference for an application start failure. (I ran application:start(sasl) from the shell.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [patch](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/c540bf517b9264cbbf48fdb51f29645269d2f991) (tp/supervisor-pass-on-errors) that was included in release R16B. This patch makes exit reasons appear in application stop log messages, which thus become much more useful than the `{shutdown,{ui_app,start,[normal,[]]}}`-style messages we've had until now.

This is the entry in the [README](http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B.readme):

> ```
> OTP-10490  == stdlib ==
>
>     If a child process fails in its start function, then the
>     error reason was earlier only reported as an error report
>     from the error_handler, and supervisor:start_link would only
>     return {error,shutdown}. This has been changed so the
>     supervisor will now return {error,{shutdown,Reason}}, where
>     Reason identifies the failing child and its error reason.
>     (Thanks to Tomas Pihl)
> ```

Comment: It didn't make it into R15B03 either, but it *is* in R16B01.  This change is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pain, but the way I do it is the old fashioned way, by writing io:format's into the start function of the application (ie the code of the module with the behaviour of application) and working out which line fails :(

Sometimes brute force and ignorance is your only man...

Comment: Yea - I _hate_ sticking io:formats in the code just to find out where a crash is... which the Erlang stack traces would give exact line numbers for these type of things as stack traces do in other languages.

Comment: Instead of using io:format, it's better to use eunit debug macros, such as ?debugHere(), ?debugVal(Val), ?debugMsg(Msg) or ?debugFmt(String, [Arg1, Arg2, ...]).

Comment: Well since this comment was written by me - the new release (R15B) of Erlang now has the line numbers in the stacktrace.